# Importing georeferenced 3D objects (Collada DAE) into ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, collada, agisoft-photoscan

I need to import 3D objects created with Agisoft Photoscan into ArcGis Desktop 10.4.1 (specifically ArcScene). I know how to use the "Import 3D" function to import Collada files as Multipatch files in Arc. There is a problem, however, with the georeferencing of these models as they are in a projected geographic (UTM) coordinate system. This has something to do with the length of the coordinate integers (xxxxxxx.xxxxxx). I know of the "work-around" where one exports two versions of the Collada model from Photoscan - one in local coordinates and one in the geographic coordinate system. You can then import the geographic coordinate model into ArcScene and use the "Replace with Model" function to import the local coordinate version model and fix the bizarre blocky visualization. However, when I do this I notice that there is a slight shift in the location of the models. They are off by a few cm in both x and y, and slightly rotated as well. This means that the models are not correctly positioned in relation to other raster and vector files in the GIS.

I've figured out that I can get around this issue by shortening the length of the UTM coordinates before the decimal when exporting from Photoscan (using the "shift" input). Models with geographic coordinates such as xxx.xxxxxx do not suffer from the same location shift, but this is unfortunate as I have to manually shift every vector and raster in the GIS project to match these shortened coordinates.

Does anyone know of a way to get ArcGIS Desktop to properly display and located full UTM coordinates with imported Collada files?

Comment: You mention "coordinate integers", but your coordinates have decimal places, thus they are *real numbers*, not integers. I mention this not to nitpick, but in case there's some confusion in data type during the import.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I think the answer must have something to do with the way ArcGIS stores the coordinates - either as float or double but with not enough precision? Is there a way to change this, either in ArcGIS or Photoscan, that would prevent me from truncating the coordinates?